# How to prove that $x\lfloor\frac{a}{x+1}\rfloor\geq \lfloor\frac{a}{2}\rfloor$, where $a\geq2$, $1\leq x\leq a-1$， $a$ and $x$ are integers.

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have worked on this question for an hour. It since obvious if without $\lfloor\rfloor$, can I have a hint?

Comment: In this case, that is $6\geq 4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $ a \ge x+1$ we can let $a = m(x+1) + b$ where $0 \le b \le x$.

Then $$x\left \lfloor \frac{a}{x+1} \right \rfloor = mx = \left \lfloor \frac{2mx+1}{2} \right \rfloor  \ge \left \lfloor \frac{m}{2}(x+1) + \frac x2 \right \rfloor \ge \left \lfloor \frac{m}{2}(x+1) + \frac b2 \right \rfloor =  \left \lfloor \frac a2 \right \rfloor $$

Comment: Why does the third "$=$" hold, it since $2mx+1\neq mx+m+x$?

Comment: $ \left \lfloor a\right \rfloor=\left \lfloor a + \frac 12 \right \rfloor$ for all integers $a$ as $a \le a + \frac 12  < a+1$.

Comment: Thinks, I get it, the third "$=$" since to be "$\geq$" as $2mx+1\geq mx+m+x $

Comment: good catch! I'll make the edit